# Subsetting data between 13:30:00 and 13:32:00 works on mac but not on windows, why?

Tags: r, date, time, subset

I have some timeseries of CO2 concentration. I'm trying to extract data between  13:30:00 and 13:32:00 but it's not working on windows.

```
 head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups: Sensor [1]
  Sensor Date       Time   CO2.ppm. Type   calCO2
  <fctr> <date>     <time>    <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1 N1     2019-02-12 13:30       583 Naveed    400
2 N1     2019-02-12 13:30       583 Naveed    400
3 N1     2019-02-12 13:30       583 Naveed    400
4 N1     2019-02-12 13:31       583 Naveed    400
5 N1     2019-02-12 13:32       583 Naveed    400
6 N1     2019-02-12 13:33       583 Naveed    400
```

This works on mac but not windows, any thoughts why?:

```
require(lubridate)
#require(tidyverse) 

subset(df,Time>=hms("13:30:00") & Time < hms("13:32:00"))
```

Comment: Try with `dplyr::filter` instead of `subset`.

Comment: Thanks patL, Could you elaborate on that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `as.POSIXct()` to create a date/time column and subset then.

```
d$Date.px <- as.POSIXct(paste(d$Date, d$Time))
subset <- d[d$Date.px < as.POSIXct("2019-02-12 13:32"), ]
# > subset
#   Sensor       Date  Time CO2.ppm.   Type calCO2             Date.px
# 2     N1 2019-02-12 13:30      583 Naveed    400 2019-02-12 13:30:00
# 3     N1 2019-02-12 13:30      583 Naveed    400 2019-02-12 13:30:00
# 4     N1 2019-02-12 13:30      583 Naveed    400 2019-02-12 13:30:00
# 5     N1 2019-02-12 13:31      583 Naveed    400 2019-02-12 13:31:00
```

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(Sensor = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("<fctr>", 
"N1"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("<date>", "2019-02-12"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("<time>", 
    "13:30", "13:31", "13:32", "13:33"), class = "factor"), CO2.ppm. = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("<dbl>", "583"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("<chr>", 
    "Naveed"), class = "factor"), calCO2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("<dbl>", "400"), class = "factor"), 
    Date.px = structure(c(1549974600, 1549974600, 1549974600, 
    1549974660, 1549974720, 1549974780), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Can you elaborate on why I need to parse date and time together to achieve this? Also, why do you think my above function works on mac but not on windows?

Comment: Welcome! Since I'm working on windows or linux machines I'm not sure why your code won't work on a mac. Perhaps something in the `lubridate` package somehow dissonates with mac. I therefore gave you a base R solution, where we AFAIK usually work with combined date/time formats and simply no single time format exists because it's not unambiguously by itself. Does that make sense for you?